# bottom tabs not on all screens despite being nested

Tags: react-native, expo

```
export default function Navigation({ colorScheme }: { colorScheme: 
ColorSchemeName }) { 
    return ( 
     <NavigationContainer 
     linking= {LinkingConfiguration} 
     theme={colorScheme === 'dark' ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}> 
     <RootNavigator /> 
</NavigationContainer> ); }


function RootNavigator() {
  return (
  <Stack.Navigator  screenOptions={{
  headerShown: false}}
  >
  <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={BottomTabNavigator} options={{ headerShown: false 
  }} />
  <Stack.Screen name="NotFound" component={NotFoundScreen} options={{ title: 'Oops!' }} 
   />
  <Stack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: 'fullScreenModal' }}>
  <Stack.Screen name="Modal" component={ModalScreen} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Paywall1" component={Paywall1Screen}  />
  <Stack.Screen name="Paywall" component={PaywallScreen} />
   <Stack.Screen name="WelcomeScreen" component={WelcomeScreen} />
  </Stack.Group>
  </Stack.Navigator>
 );
}
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator<RootTabParamList>();

function BottomTabNavigator() {
const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

return (
<BottomTab.Navigator
  initialRouteName="HomeScreen"
  screenOptions={{
    headerShown: false,
    tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors[colorScheme].tint,
  }}>
  <BottomTab.Screen
    name="HomeScreen"
    component={HomeScreen}
    options={{
      tabBarLabel: 'Today',
      tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarIcon name="home" color= 
 {color} />,
    }}
  />
  <BottomTab.Screen
    name="Episodes"
    component={EpisodesScreen}
    options={{
      title: 'Episodes',
      tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarFeatherIcon 
   name="headphones" color={color} />,
    }}
  />
    <BottomTab.Screen
    name="TabThree"
    component={TabThreeScreen}
    options={{
      title: 'Guides',
      tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarFeatherIcon name="bookmark" color={color} />,
    }}
  />
    <BottomTab.Screen
    name="CommunityScreen"
    component={CommunityScreen}
    options={{
      title: 'Community',
      tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarIcon name="users" color= 
      {color} />,
    }}
  />
    <BottomTab.Screen
    name="ProfileScreen"
    component={ProfileScreen}
    options={{
      title: 'Profile',
      tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarIcon name="user" color= 
{color} />,
    }}
  />
</BottomTab.Navigator>
 );
}
```

Using EXPO version 43.0.1 with react-navigation/core 6.1.0 react-navigation/bottom-tabs 6.0.9

I need the bottomTabNavigator to show on all screens and not just the 5 i have listed in my bottomTabNavigator. nothing on here seems to help with this just the opposite of keeping them off the screens the user doesnt want them on.

For example if i'm on my Paywall screen i do not see my bottomTabs (this route is not included in the bottomTabNavigator)

Comment: What's the entire component look like? What version of React Navigation?

Answer (score 0):

At the current moment in your question you do not mention what version or the entire file for the component `RootNavigator`. At glance, if you're using React Navigation 6 it needs a `NavigationContainer` and I don't see that in your question, example with `NavigationContainer`:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()

const RootNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen name='Root' component={BottomTabNavigator} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen name='NotFound' component={NotFoundScreen} options={{ title: 'Oops!' }} />
        <Stack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: 'fullScreenModal' }}>
          <Stack.Screen name='Modal' component={ModalScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name='Paywall1' component={Paywall1Screen} />
          <Stack.Screen name='Paywall' component={PaywallScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name='WelcomeScreen' component={WelcomeScreen} />
        </Stack.Group>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

export default RootNavigator
```

Comment: using EXPO with the navigation prebuilt

Comment: export default function Navigation({ colorScheme }: { colorScheme: ColorSchemeName }) {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      linking={LinkingConfiguration}
      theme={colorScheme === 'dark' ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
      <RootNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
   );
}

Comment: dont include it as a comment make an edit to your question.

Comment: edit of the question is done